# Oracle SOA-BPEL accessing nested XML elements for variable assignment

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, soa, bpel

I have a use case related to XPath query issue regarding nested XML data access. Kindly check the below screenshot:

[image]

Additionally, below is the schema part of TargetEntityData
[image]

Now scenario is that, I have to assign **Value** From **DataAttribute** to right hand side element **Approver_DiscomID** based on the corresponding **Name** attribute in left hand side i.e.

if **Name**=usr_discom then Approver_DiscomID=Value (from screenshot schema it would be like if Name='usr_discom' then Approver_DiscomID='Discom3')

if **Name**=usr_division then Approver_DivisionID=Value (from screenshot schema it would be like if Name='usr_division' then Approver_DivisionID='PVVNL0920939')
and so on .

Any idea how to do manipulation in xpath.

Thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!

Need below XPath Expression:

```
bpws:getVariableData('requestDetails','RequestData','/ns18:RequestData/ns18:TargetEntityData/ns18:TargetEntity/ns18:DataAttribute[@Name="district"]/@Value')
```

Here @Name refers to TargetEntityData => TargetEntity => DataAtribute => Name

Now there is **/@Value** is appended to to it. So it will return the Value of attribute Name district & so on.